What should I do if I want both a C-focused and C++-focused answer to an otherwise identical/very similar question?
Sometimes I ask questions about C but the rules may be different in C++, for example, in C you can use a union to type-pun, but in C++, doing so is undefined behavior. C++ is a separate language, but was created as an extension of C, so most of the C-inherited features are the same, but not all of them.
If I have a question, and want both a C-focused and C++-focused answer, but the question is otherwise the same, should I:

Ask 2 separate questions that are seemingly the same, except one is tagged C and the other C++? How can I avoid having one closed as a duplicate of the other, if the answers happen to be the same?
Include a sentence asking if the behavior the same in C as in C++? If so, how should I tag the question and avoid having the question closed as needs more focus?


I'm not really an SME but I'd try posting the question for C++ first, if I can't use the posted answers in C I'll ask another question for C.

"C++ is a separate language, but was created as an extension of C" - the latter doesn't matter anymore, it is just trivia. It is a separate language. A VERY separate language.

@Gimby that's context sensitive. If you're trying to write good code, then yes. If you're trying to understand the memory model, not so much.


Ask 2 separate questions that are seemingly the same, except one is tagged C and the other C++? How can I avoid having one closed as a duplicate of the other, if the answers happen to be the same?

Ask (without loss of generality) a C question and wait for it to be answered. (Or locate one that already exists.) Then ask about the corresponding issue in C++, in the form: "I know that in C, it works [this way](link to the C question). Is it the same in C++?"
If the answer is "yes", then the question is in my mind still not a duplicate. A qualifying answer would simply say "yes", and show any necessary adapted-to-C++ code to illustrate that this is in fact the case. It shouldn't take more than one answer to accomplish this. That answer should have enough detail that future C++ askers don't feel bad about getting dupe-hammered to the C++ question, but not so much as to duplicate what the C Q&A says.
Otherwise, it's a normal question that stands on its own as if the C question never existed. In a lot of cases, the answer is "almost", after all. (And the devil really is in the details when working with a language like either C or C++, with undefined behaviour lurking behind every corner.)
